# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Tags: android, firebase, gson, stripe-payments

I have been really searching for answers but no one is responding to me. I am just trying to add payment to my firebase app using stripe I am [following this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) but my app keeps crashing cause of some error which I have  no idea how to fix `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` and its telling me that this line is the problem

> ```
>     Map<String, String> responseMap gson.fromJson(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),type);
> ```

but how am I supposed to fix it?  I understand its expecting an object but its given a string but how am I supposed to make it an object?

Comment: can you add to your question, what is the logged out value for `response.body()`?

Comment: @hmunoz My question is how can I solve that error. I'm following everything from the stripe documentation

Comment: Can you provide the link to the Stripe guide you are referencing? Also if you can log out the response.body() and paste that too, that would really help us find the right answer for you, thanks!

Comment: @hmunoz I edited my question and I put the tutorial link. As far as the lgout for the response body I'm not sure I just followed along wit the tutorial

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but your line doesn't seem to be mysterious. What about changing the `Map` type and getting rid of the `.string()`: `Map<String, Object> responseMap gson.fromJson(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()),type);`

Comment: I Just did that but that isn't a good format